# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while loop with charat()

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, char, stack

After an hour of looking for an solution in stackoverflow and other forums I gave up.

Do you have an idea why I am getting the exception?

```
    public Stack<Character> einlesen(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();
    System.out.println("Please insert any random text: \n");

    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        try {
            String eingabe;

            eingabe = is.readLine();

            int i = 0;
            while (eingabe.charAt(i) != -1  ) {
                st.push(eingabe.charAt(i));
                i++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return st;
```

Edit:

Thanks to Elliot its working perfectly.

If I want to rewrite all the characters in the stack now in the opposite order I tried to use following code. But it only writes a few characters. When I use the peek function it gives me all of them.

So I guess there is smth wrong with "i

```
    for ( int i =0; i<st.size();i++) {
        System.out.print(st.pop().toString());
    }
```

Comment: Strings, `eingabe`, don't ever return -1.  Read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is not `C` (and -1 is not '\0' even if it were), this

```
while (eingabe.charAt(i) != -1  ) {
  st.push(eingabe.charAt(i));
  i++;
}
```

Should be

```
while (i < eingabe.length()) {
  st.push(eingabe.charAt(i));
  i++;
}
```

or,

```
for (char ch : eingabe.toCharArray()) {
  st.push(ch);
}
```

Because Java `String` does not have an end of `String` character.

Comment: Thanks again Elliott :D Works perfectly. You also helped me on my scanner question before!

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have an idea why I am getting the exception?

Yea ...

It is impossible for your `eingabe` string to contain a character that equals `-1`.  (Even the character`0xffff` is going to convert into the integer `65535`.)  So your while loop is simply indexing off the end of the string.

(And Java strings are not terminated by any particular character anyway.  Java ain't C or C++.)

Use `eingabe.length()` to tell you when to stop ...

---

> After an hour of looking for an solution in stackoverflow and other forums I gave up.

Here's some free advice:

What you are doing is NOT the right way to solve program problems.  The right way to program is to read and understand your code, based on your knowledge of the Java language and the class libraries.  If you don't have the knowledge yet ...

1. Do the Oracle Java Tutorials, or buy and read a good beginners Java textbook.
2. Read the javadocs for the classes that you are attempting to use.

Googling for solutions to simple programming problems is probably a waste of time.  You won't learn much, and there is a good chance you will find incorrect or inappropriate solutions, and/or you won't recognize the right solutions when you see them.

Comment: Your advice is worth gold ! Thanks a lot. Actually this problem here is part of an excercise of a Java beginners book. I checked the API before but very well. I will stick more to your advice and try not to use anything else but the API :) On the long run it will be easier to face my java problems if I fully understand the API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a for loop for this.

```
        String eingabe;

        eingabe = is.readLine();

        for( int i = 0; i < eingabe.length(); i++ ) {
            st.push(eingabe.charAt(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

for `charAt`, index i must be between 0 and the length of the string minus 1 (both ends inclusive). When i equals length(), you get index out of bound exception.

Here is [the document for String charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)).

Here is one way to solve this:

```
while (i < eingabe.length()) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for your second question:
Yes the problem is in the for loop for retrieving the elements from the stack. You should not manipulate the data structure especially when you are iterating it based on the size. The piece of the code in the for loop removes an element from the stack (which means the size is reduced by 1) and the looping variable is incremented by 1. That is the reason why you are getting only the half of the data.

I hope the below piece of code will help.

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>(); 
String name = "Loganathan";

for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
    stack.push(c);
}

StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
while (! stack.isEmpty()) {
    buff.append(stack.pop());
}

System.out.println("Retrieved from the stack : " + buff.toString());
```